# How to add style to html element in typescript and angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to set property flex-grow to element but its not working.

script:

```
(this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).setAttribute(
      'style',
      'flex-grow:' + this.panel.width && this.panel.width.type === 1 ? '0' : '1'
    );
```

the final result:

```
<ev-panel class="ev-panel ng-star-inserted" style="0" ng-reflect-panel="[object Object]"></ev-panel>
<ev-panel class="ev-panel ng-star-inserted" style="0" ng-reflect-panel="[object Object]"></ev-panel>
<ev-panel class="ev-panel ng-star-inserted" style="1" ng-reflect-panel="[object Object]"></ev-panel>
```

looks like it works fine, but where is flex-grow? I am asking for help and understanding

Comment: What happens if you put the shorthand if else statement between brackets?

Comment: Style takes object. I guess you need to add the flex-grow shorthand as object

Comment: @Mohit style does not accept a object. Just like any other attribute, it takes a string :)

Comment: @PoulKruijt Yes I know, I wanna say something like while doing interpolation syntax, it takes object of styles i.e. <div style={{display:'flex'}} /> in react. Though I think it's some syntax issue in the above code. I've posted the answer. Let's see if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using angular, you just use `@HostBinding`:

```
export class PanelComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.flex-grow')
  get flexGrow(): string {
    return this.panel?.type === 1 ? '0' : '1'
  }
}
```

the reason your code is not working though, is because you are missing parentheses. The entire statement in front of the question mark is evaluated first, including the `flex-grow` string. To do it your way (not advisable) you should do it like this:

```
(this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).setAttribute(
  'style',
  'flex-grow:' + (this.panel.width && this.panel.width.type === 1 ? '0' : '1')
);
```

and with the latest angular/typescript version, you can also use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

```
(this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).setAttribute(
  'style',
  `flex-grow: ${this.panel.width?.type === 1 ? '0' : '1'}`
);
```

but again, `@HostBinding` is the way to go, if you are using angular

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
((this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).setAttribute(
      'style',
      `flex-grow: ${this.panel.width && this.panel.width.type === 1 ? 0 : 1}`
    );
```

Hope this will set the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Angular Renderer2,
is an abstraction provided by Angular in the form of a service that allows to manipulate elements of your app without having to touch the DOM directly. This is the recommended approach.

```
     constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {

     const flexGrowValue = + this.panel.width && this.panel.width.type === 1 ? '0' : '1';

     this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'flex-grow',flexGrowValue  )

   }
```

https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Simple example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3wyy4g